# Can we replace a latch with a buffer or vice versa?

Tags: io, buffer, microcontroller

I've been reading about **latches** and **buffers** with repsect to their usage in extending the **IO** capabilities of microcontrollers and i came to this question:

> What is the main reason that we can't replace a latch with a buffer or vice versa?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not interchangeable.  They are different chips because they do very different things.

A buffer takes data and "boosts" it to increase the number of devices the data can be routed to.  A buffer can be used to increase the drive power of the signal, level-shift from one drive level to another (like 5V to 3.3V or vice versa), and to increase the "fan out" or drive power of a signal.  It doesn't "remember" anything and is really used typically to provide more signal fanout and also to provide resonance in simple feed back circuits.

A latch, on the other hand, **holds** (latches) the data put into it until it is cleared.  A perfect example of latching behavior is with the 7447 BCD 7-segment display decoders.  You put in a 4-bit input, and then the chip *latches* that input and drives the LED display while your controller moves on to encode another digit or do other work, rather than continuously refreshing the display.  The *latching* behavior of the chip "remembers" the last value entered and keeps using it on its output, providing a stable input for the LED display.

Comment: Thanks. My own answer to this question was a bit out of reach i guess. Your's was super clear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No**, We **can't**!

To be simple, The buffer devices(**Chips**) are made of some internal **Digital Buffers** and are widely used as **Input**s while extending the number of input ports.

In contrast to that, there is a device called **Latch** that is made of some internal **Flip-flop**s and they are used as **Output**s while extending the number of output devices.

The followings are three major differences between the **buffer** and **latch** and the reason they can't be used alternatively is pretty clear.

- **Buffer** has the capability to protect the input by **Power Ampilification**.
- **Buffer** is used to make sure that the input signal is **Super Robust**.
- **Buffer** uses the concept of **Propagation Delay** to increase the stability of the input by increasing it's **Fan-out**.

While,

- **Latch** will make the output to be a bit more **Memory** like by using **D-FF** in it's structure.(Whereas buffers don't)
- **Latch** uses the **Clock** pulse in order to pass the data to it's output.
- **Latch** is mainly used to **Capture** it's input and **Persist** that input to it's output ports.

So there are real differences in terms of their characterstics and they have to be applied in their particular field of use.